# JavaScript Remove Duplicate Tags on Div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I delete the same text on the tag element?
In this case I have found this trick:

```js
var seen = '';

       $('div').each(function() {
         var see = $(this).text();
         if (seen.match(see)) {
           $(this).remove();
         } else {
           seen = $(this).text();
         }
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Book</div>
<div>Book</div>
<div>Book</div>
<div>Pencil</div>
<div>Pencil</div>
<div>Book Book Book Pencil Pencil</div>
```

The above code is not wrong. Because I have the same few words wrapped in the same tag.

```
<div>Book Book Book Pencil Pencil</div>
```

Is there a way around this problem?

Edit: I want to change into `<div>Book Pencil</div>`

Comment: what should happen if you have divs like  `<div>Book</div><div>Pencil</div><div>Book Book Book Pencil Pencil</div><div>Book</div><div>Pencil</div>`?

Comment: @Aruna If the result `<div>Book</ div><div>Pencil</ div>` also nice. Is there a way?

Comment: @satriabajakan you want ``<div>Book</ div><div>Pencil</ div>`` to become ``<div>Book Pencil</div>``?

Comment: @satriabajakan You can check below

Comment: @DonaldWu Yes, whatever it is, provided that the results could change the text of twins, that's what I want

Comment: @satriabajakan I have given two examples below with the same script and it works well for both the cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given a nice solution below.

Note: The following two examples work well with the same script as you expected. It's a generic script and will work for both examples

**Example 1**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Book</div>
<div>Book</div>
<div>Book</div>
<div>Pencil</div>
<div>Pencil</div>
<div>Book</div>
<div>Book Book Book Pencil Pencil</div>


<script>
var tags = [];
   $('div').each(function(){
       var tagArray = $(this).text().split(' ');
     
       for(var i = tagArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          var tag = tagArray[i];
          if(tags.indexOf(tag) > -1) {
             tagArray.splice(i, 1);
          } else {
            tags.push(tag);
          }
       }
     
       var currentTag = tagArray.join(' ');
     
        if(currentTag){
            $(this).text(currentTag);
        }
        else{
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Example 2**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Book Book Book Pencil Pencil</div>


<script>
var tags = [];
   $('div').each(function(){
       var tagArray = $(this).text().split(' ');
     
       for(var i = tagArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          var tag = tagArray[i];
          if(tags.indexOf(tag) > -1) {
             tagArray.splice(i, 1);
          } else {
            tags.push(tag);
          }
       }
     
       var currentTag = tagArray.join(' ');
     
        if(currentTag){
            $(this).text(currentTag);
        }
        else{
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: there is no use to use `each` method in 2nd example

Comment: @Mahi Thats a generic script works for both examples as OP requested. Check the first script and second which both are same and should work for both cases.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

i want to show you where you were wrong nothing else

```js
var seen='';
var array=document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML.split(" ");
array.forEach(function(a,index){
        var see=a;
        if(seen.match(see)){
            array.splice(index, 1);}
        else{
            seen=seen+a+" ";
        }
    });

$("div").text(seen);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Book Book Book Pencil Pencil</div>
```

Comment: You solution completely broken for this case `<div>Book</div> <div>Book</div> <div>Pencil</div> <div>Book</div> <div>Pencil</div>`

Comment: Yes it has mentioned in the question. Check the concepts what he mentioned. He should want to remove the duplicate tags :-)

Comment: @Aruna if we assumed to pass all test cases then your code also won't work if div is nested.

Comment: @Mahi why tag should be nested? You still didn't understand the concept :-) I can't make you understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var seen = '';

$('div').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/(^|\s+)(\S+)(($|\s+)\2)+/gi, "$1$2"));
  var see = $(this).text();
  if (seen.match(see)) {
    $(this).remove();
  } else {
    seen = $(this).text();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Book</div>
<div>Book</div>
<div>Book</div>
<div>Pencil</div>
<div>Pencil</div>
<div>Book Book Book Pencil Pencil pencil Pencil * * . . .</div>
<div>Book</div> <div>Book</div> <div>Pencil</div> <div>Book</div> <div>Pencil</div>
```

Comment: You solution seems to be not working for this case `<div>Book</div>
<div>Book</div>
<div>Pencil</div>
<div>Book</div>
<div>Pencil</div>`

Comment: I have added that to the snippet. It is working. Or should it be some other way that OP wants it?

Comment: Check your divs and the divs I gave. In your div all `Book` div comes first then `Pencil` div. But its broken if it comes alternatively like, `Book, Pencil, Book, Pencil`.

Comment: Ok, I thought OP wanted to remove *consecutive* repetitions. Looks like OP want so remove all repetitions across all divs.